# Matching LIGHT theme for Intellij Idea (Java) and Xcode (Swift)

Tags: xcode, themes, jetbrains-ide, iterm2

I was wondering if anyone here has a matching light theme for Intellij (Java) and Xcode (Swift) and iTerm2 (Shell)

By matching, that means they look very similar (for instance, the Material Light theme, which exists for both Intellij and Xcode does not look alike at all when put next to each other).

By light theme, nothing dark mode, if possible, not too many colors in the light one.

If possible, really for Xcode, not AppCode. And really for Intellij, not eclipse.

If possible, some screenshot would be great.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15727-xcode-theme

But I like xcode-dark theme the most you can find it here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13106-xcode-dark-theme